# Is there any way to Install postgres from Binary in linux machine irrespective of Linux build(Debian/CentOS/others)

Tags: linux, debian, centos, postgresql

I am trying to install postgres on different machine using ansible. Currently I am using postgres source to install on a partical location.

Its taking too much time. Is their a way to run postgres by simpy unzipping a tar or zip binary file like that of tomcat zip.

If any alternative is their please suggest me one. :)

Comment: Do you know ansible galaxy? Would it not be easier using ansible gathering facts phase to write rules installing the official packages depending on the distributions you use?

Comment: I know but i want to install postgres in a specific location, so it will be easy if i could just unzip and start post gres :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using ansible already.  Just let ansible do the right thing and install the appropriate packages specific to each distro, using the native package manager for each distro.

Otherwise, you're going to have to build and compile your own version of postgresql for each platform and package them yourself.  Postgresql isn't a java application, it is written in C and needs to be compile for each platform based on what is available.